# Merge multiple arrays by index

Tags: php, arrays, merge

Im some array that's being returned by some query.. and the result is something like this:

```
array(array('balance_1'=> '-5', 'balance_2'=>'-21'), array('balance_1'=> '-21', 'balance_2'=>'21'), array('balance_1'=> '-50', 'balance_2'=>'40'))
```

i want to transform this into an array that looks something like this:

```
array(array(-5,11,-50), array(-21, 21, 40));
```

basicly i want to join all balance_1, all balance_2, all balance_3 into separated arrays.

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll just loop over the list, then collect the values. It's most simple if you reuse the existing keys to group:

```
foreach ($list as $row) {
    foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
        $out[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

This way you'll get an `$out` array, with `[balance_1]` or `[balance_2]` holding the value lists.

Answer (score -1):

Loop though the array and use "array_key_exists" if the key exists add to the array, if it doesn't build a new array with your index.

For more can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php