# Finding matching keys in a multidimensional array and storing them in new array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to parse a multidimensional array and store all the matching keys into their own array.

Input Array:

```
    array (
    [Items] => Array (
        [0] => AS1585.AGG
        [1] => AS1585.AGG
        [2] => ZBRK-1776
        [3] => ZBRK-2076
        [4] => ZBRK-3001
    )
    [Qty2] => Array (
        [0] => 5
        [1] => 5
        [2] => 5
        [3] => 5
        [4] => 6
    )
    [Cost] => Array (
        [0] => $351.00
        [1] => $351.00
        [2] => $437.00
        [3] => $380.00
        [4] => $358.00
    )
    [TotalCubes2] => Array (
        [0] => 168.40
        [1] => 168.40
        [2] => 186.05
        [3] => 161.25
        [4] => 140.70
    )
    [TotalCost2] => Array (
        [0] => $1755.00
        [1] => $1755.00
        [2] => $2185.00
        [3] => $1900.00
        [4] => $2148.00
    )
)
```

Desired output:

```
Array (
    [Items] => AS1585.AGG
    [Qty2] => 5
    [Cost] => $351.00
    [TotalCubes2] => 168.40
    [TotalCost2] => $1755.00
)
```

Comment: Still cannot understand it. Matching keys, matching... what?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270723/4606122

Comment: Thank you dass!! I searched all over stackoverflow for something similar.  That worked like a charm..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge multiple arrays by index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270715/merge-multiple-arrays-by-index)